# identifying and assigning +NaN and -NaN in C

Tags: c, floating-point, nan

I have to get input in `float` as +NaN or -NaN and convert to another artificial floating form called `tinyfp` (1 sign bit, 3 exponent bits, 4 fraction bits) for one question,

or get input in the tinyfp (each presenting +NaN or -NaN) and answer as either +NaN or -NaN

The question specifically asks

> +NaN and -NaN in float should be converted to the corresponding +NaN and -NaN in tinyfp, respectively.

and

> +NaN and -NaN in tinyfp should be converted to the corresponding +NaN and -NaN in float, respectively.

---

The first problem is, since I cannot compare NaN to anything (even itself), while I can identify if input value is NaN, I cannot distinguish between +NaN and -NaN.

Similar with second problem, when I want to answer as either +NaN or -NaN, both 0.0/0.0 and -0.0/0.0 are represented as -NaN, so I cannot answer anything as +NaN.

I tried `if( input == 0.0/0.0)` or `(input == -0.0/0.0)`, and they don't work.
I can try `if(input != input)`, but then I can't distinguish +NaN and -NaN.

For the second problem, I tried `return 0.0/0.0` and `return -0.0/0.0`, but both end up answering as -NaN. (while somehow I can get input as both nan and -nan)

---

So the question is, how do I check if input is +NaN or -NaN, and how do I assign +NaN and -NaN differently when I want to answer as NaN?

I'm not allowed to use any header other than stdio.h + and I can't use `double` format as well - only `float` allowed

Comment: Even if defined in math.h, you should have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/nan, https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/signbit and https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/copysign and their implementation.

Comment: i'm looking through the page and I can't find how they implemented it - the page only explains how to use the method they have available... is it just me not able to find how math.h does it?

Comment: Possible implementation of `copysign` here: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libiberty/copysign.c

Comment: i just tried it, but trying copysign(0.0/0.0, 2) gives a zero, not +nan that I need.

Comment: @Kwon it should work. See the example in the `copysign` document. The problem is likely in your printing function

Answer (score 2):

Your limitations on which functions / headers you may use give a strong impression that you are expected to directly analyze and manipulate the representations of `float`s.  That would also presume an assumption of a specific `float` representation, but big-endian IEEE-754 binary32 format is a pretty good bet.  I presume you've already been studying this.

You can access the representation of a float value through an `unsigned char` pointer:

```
_Bool my_isnan(float f) {
    unsigned char *bytes = (unsigned char *) &f;
    // analyze bytes[0], bytes[1], etc. ...
}
```

You can manipulate `float` representations by similar means.

I leave the details of the analyses / manipulations to you, as that seems to be the key point of the exercise, and I'm not going to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not allowed to use `math.h` then you're on your own and must extract information about the float value from its binary representation. To do that you need to understand how floats are stored in the [IEEE-754 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) (assuming `float` is [IEEE-754 single precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)). If you don't know how floating-point types are stored then how can you construct the value in tinyfp?

So basically a float is represented as `s eeeeeeee mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm` with the 3 parts being sign-exponent-mantissa respectively. You just need to get the underlying bits using various ways. Then check `if (eeeeeeee == 0xFF)` because the largest exponent is reserved for inf and nan in IEEE-754. Now read the mantissa to know whether it's inf or nan. Getting the sign of `±inf` and `±nan` is trivial as you already have the sign bit. All of that have been specified in the standard, just check it

- [get the integer representation value of a float type variable in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36125638/995714)
- [Convert float to bigint (aka portable way to get binary exponent & mantissa)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2133903/995714)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `isnan` and `isinf` functions.

To create inf and -inf numbers you could use 1.0/0.0 (should give inf) and -1.0/0.0 (should give -inf).

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
  double x = 1.0/0.0;
  double y = -1.0/0.0;
  double z = sqrt(-1.0);
  printf("x = %f\n", x);
  printf("y = %f\n", y);
  printf("isinf(x) = %d\n", isinf(x));
  printf("isinf(y) = %d\n", isinf(y));
  printf("isnan(x) = %d\n", isnan(x));
  printf("isnan(z) = %d\n", isnan(z));
}
```

Comment: i'm not allowed to use math.h header. I have no problem with inf and -inf, the nan and -nan are the troubles

Comment: @Kwon but why do you think there is such a thing as a "negative" nan? I think inf can be + or - but nan cannot. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: @Elias NaNs have the sign bit, settable with `copysign` and readable with `signbit`.